# Does $[F(\zeta_n) : F ]$ divide $\phi(n)$?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I know that if $F=\mathbb Q$, the degree actually equals $\phi(n)$. Also, if the extension $F(\zeta_n)/F$ is Galois, then I can invoke my knowledge of the existence of an injective map from $Gal(F(\zeta_n),F$) to ${(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z})^*$ to argue that the degree, which equals the order of the Galois group, must divide $\phi(n)$ since the Galois group itself is isomorphic to a subgroup of a group of order $\phi(n)$ via the injective map.

My question is, is it true in general that $[F(\zeta_n) : F ]$ divides $\phi(n)$? If yes, please give a proof. If not, I'd appreciate a counterexample. Maybe I'm missing something completely trivial here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: But $F(\zeta_n)$ is the splitting field of $X^n-1$ over $F$. Thus normal.

Comment: But I don't see why it's seperable. I need the extension to be Galois to be able to do it this way.

Comment: Sorry, I thought you were in characteristic zero. In case you’re in characteristic $p$, let $n=p^em$, with $m$ prime to $p$. Then $x^n-1=(x^m-1)^{p^e}$, and the separable polynomial you’re looking for is $x^m-1$. As you see, its roots are the same as those of $x^n-1$.